# Remove elements from several lists simultaneously

Tags: python

I have three lists with the same length and another list that stores indexes of elements that I need to remove from all three lists. This is an example of what I mean:

```
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1,2,8,784,43,6,2]
c = [8,4,32,6,1,7,2,9,23]
```

(all have `len()=9`)

The other list contains the indexes of those elements I need to remove from all three lists:

```
d = [8,5,3]
```

(note that it is already sorted)

I know I can remove one element at the time from the three lists with:

```
for indx in d:
    del a[indx]
    del b[indx]
    del c[indx]
```

How could I do this in one single line?

Comment: Do you need three separate lists? If not, zip them together and modify just one: `d = zip(a, b, c)`.

Comment: Or, if you need them to have names, what about storing them as values in a `dict` with keys `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`? Then it's just `for index in indices:` `for v in d.values():` `del v[index]`.

Comment: When problems like this come up, it indicates that your data is not organized the way it ought to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `numpy` is useful for something like this, if your three lists were a 2D `numpy.array` deleting specified columns would be very easy.

```
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1,2,8,784,43,6,2]
c = [8,4,32,6,1,7,2,9,23]

big_array = np.array([a,b,c])

d = [8,5,3]
```

Result:

```
>>> big_array
array([[  3,   4,   5,  12,   6,   8,  78,   5,   6],
       [  6,   4,   1,   2,   8, 784,  43,   6,   2],
       [  8,   4,  32,   6,   1,   7,   2,   9,  23]])
>>> np.delete(big_array, d, axis=1)
array([[ 3,  4,  5,  6, 78,  5],
       [ 6,  4,  1,  8, 43,  6],
       [ 8,  4, 32,  1,  2,  9]])
```

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of the `np.delete()` command. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Not one line, but concise, readable, and completely idiomatic Python:

```
for indx in d:
    for x in a, b, c:
        del x[indx]
```

However, the fact that you're doing this in the first place implies that maybe rather than 3 separate list variables, you should have a list of 3 lists, or a dict of three lists keyed by the names `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

---

If you really want it in one line:

```
for indx in d: a.pop(indx), b.pop(indx), c.pop(indx)
```

But that's really terrible. You're calling `pop` when you don't care about the values, and building up a `tuple` you don't need.

If you want to play code golf, you can save a few characters by using a list comprehension—which adds one more language abuse, and builds another, larger object you don't actually want—as in Ioan Alexandru Cucu's answer:

```
[x.pop(indx) for indx in d for x in a, b, c]
```

---

Of course the best way to write it in one line is to factor it out into a function:

```
def delemall(indices, *lists):
    for index in indices:
        for x in lists:
            del x[indx]
```

And now, each of the 300 times you need to do this, it's just:

```
delemall(d, a, b, c)
```

Comment: It's not one line, but it's clearly the most readable solution

Comment: +1 for the detail answer but I'm selecting Akavall's answer because it's a one liner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think just your code is OK, to make it a single line:

```
In [234]: for i in d: del a[i], b[i], c[i]

In [235]: a,b,c
Out[235]: ([3, 4, 5, 6, 78, 5], [6, 4, 1, 8, 43, 6], [8, 4, 32, 1, 2, 9])
```

but I still like leaving that for loop two lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
a = [3,4,5,12,6,8,78,5,6]
b = [6,4,1,2,8,784,43,6,2]
c = [8,4,32,6,1,7,2,9,23]
d = [8,5,3]

for _ in (operator.delitem(q,i) for q in (a,b,c) for i in d): pass

print(a,b,c)
```